# Powershell Error: The string is missing the terminator: ". / The string is missing the terminator: "@

Tags: powershell, api

When running the following code, either in ISE or Powershell window:

```
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$username="username"
$password="password"
$credPair = "$($username):$($password)"
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("content-type", "application/vnd.emc.apollo-v1+xml")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $encodedCredentials")

$body = "<runReportParameters>
`n<report>
`n<name>Report Namer</name>
`n</report>
`n<nodes>
`n<node>
`n<id>1a5e8e1a-2c47-449f-a8d4-535549fe1d69</id>
`n</node>
`n</nodes>
`n<timeConstraints type=`"window`">
`n<window>
`n<name>Last Day</name>
`n</window>
`n</timeConstraints>
`n<formatParameters>
`n<formatType>CSV</formatType>
`n</formatParameters>
`n</runReportParameters>"

[string]$response = ""
[string]$pattern = ""
[string]$url = ""

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://<hostname>:<port>/api/report' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body

$pattern = "<link>(.*)</link>"
$url = [regex]::match($response, $pattern).Groups[1].Value

Invoke-RestMethod "$url" -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

It fails with the following errors:

> **PSMessageDetails      : Exception             : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503)
> Server Unavailable.
> at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest
> request)
> at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
> TargetObject          : System.Net.HttpWebRequest CategoryInfo
>
> : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest)
> [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
> ErrorDetails          :
> https://:/api/report/result/8179ad5b-e6f8-4964-8e4f-8233df6656a2
> InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
> ScriptStackTrace      : at , : line 1
> PipelineIterationInfo : {} Errors                      : Message
>
> : The string is missing the terminator: ". ErrorRecord
>
> : The string is missing the terminator: ". WasThrownFromThrowStatement
> : False Data                        : {} InnerException              :
> TargetSite                  :
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject] Invoke(System.Collections.IEnumerable) StackTrace                  :   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Executor.ExecuteCommandHelper(Pipeline tempPipeline, Exception& exceptionThrown, ExecutionOptions options) HelpLink                    : Source                      : System.Management.Automation HResult                     : -2146233087 Errors                      : Message                     : The string is missing the terminator: "@. ErrorRecord                 : The string is missing the terminator: "@. WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False Data                        : {} InnerException              : TargetSite                  : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
> Invoke(System.Collections.IEnumerable) StackTrace                  :
>
> at
> System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
> input)
> at Microsoft.PowerShell.Executor.ExecuteCommandHelper(Pipeline
> tempPipeline, Exception& exceptionThrown, ExecutionOptions options)
> HelpLink                    : Source                      :
> System.Management.Automation HResult                     : -2146233087
> writeErrorStream      : True PSMessageDetails      : Exception
>
> : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module 'PSReadline'
> was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
> directory. TargetObject          : PSReadline CategoryInfo          :
> ResourceUnavailable: (PSReadline:String) [Import-Module],
> FileNotFoundException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
> ErrorDetails          : InvocationInfo        :
> System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo ScriptStackTrace      :
> PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1, 0}**

But, if I print the var $url a couple of times and then the Invoke-RestMethod, it works fine:

```
PS C:\Users\jump\Music> $url
https://<hostname>:<port>/api/report/result/15d56f05-b317-4cb5-8c36-59dc264ebf6f

PS C:\Users\jump\Music> Invoke-RestMethod "$url" -Method GET -Headers $headers
Server,Proxy,Job Count,GB Modified Sent
server1,proxy1,6,1.057
server2,proxy4,5,0.911
...
```

Any idea about the variable setup in ISE or Powershell??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. The thing is that the report takes some time to be generated hence the error. Adding a "sleep" solved the issue, just before the GET method:

```
Start-Sleep -s 30
Invoke-RestMethod "$url" -Method GET -Headers $headers
```